# Is it possible to intercept a constructor call with dynamic proxy?

Tags: castle-dynamicproxy

Is it possible to intercept a constructor call with dynamic proxy?
I registered a proxy on a class that only contains a constructor as a test but it's not intercepted.
I am guessing that it's currently not possible but maybe there's something special I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. For the simple reason that the creation of proxies is managed by `ProxyGenerator` which precludes using `new` with proxies.

Comment: Nope. It's one of the fundamental design decisions in Dynamic Proxy - not to alter existing IL and without altering IL you can't intercept constructor calls. You might want to check out LinFu DynamicProxy (version 2or higher) which is fundamentally different from Castle DynamicProxy and I think it does let you do those sorts of things.